# Moving a part of the screen with pygame in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm making a game, a part of which includes a chat-box style simulation. What I'm trying to do is to move a part of the screen upwards so all the text will move up and make room for more.

I've succeeded in making part of the screen black using this code:

```
def move (screen):
    area = pygame.Surface((540, 400))
    area.scroll(0, -100)
    area_rect = area.get_rect()
    area_rect = area.get_rect(left=100, bottom=400)
    area_rect.move_ip(0, -100)
    screen.blit(area, (100, 0), area_rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

I'm trying to move the area [(100, 0), (640, 400)] up by 100 pixels on a 640x480 screen. What am I doing terribly wrong?

Comment: you create empty black surface and move it. You doesn't use part of the screen surface or chat-box surface.

Comment: Ah, okay. How do I move a part of the screen surface? What is left in the part I moved it from doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use `Surface.scroll` for that. If you don't care what's left below after moving that specific area upwards, try just copying the part that you want to move and blitting it where you want it to reappear:

```
area_rect = pygame.Rect(100, 0, 540, 400)
area = screen.subsurface(area_rect)
new_area_rect = area_rect.move(0, -100)
screen.blit(area, new_area_rect.topleft)
pygame.display.flip()
```